# Updating VS Extension from 2015 to 2017 (VSIX v3) makes the package invalid

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsixmanifest

I have an older extension that i would like to get to work in VS 2017. To be able to do this i understand that i will have to use the new VSIX Manifest v3. The extension works fine in 2015 Update 3. To update it I've done the following:

1. Open the extension source in VS2017. I'm prompted to do a one-time upgrade, which is completed successfully
2. Use NuGet to update the Microsot VSSDK BuildTools from 14.x to 15.x
3. Add the Prerequisite block to the source.extension.vsixmanifest file containing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
4. Update the Installation target to also support the new Visual studio like so

   `<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,16.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />`

Builds successfully, but once i open the vsix file in my debug folder, get a message telling me

`The file is not a valid VSIX package`

If i open up the file using WinRAR i can see that the two mandatory files `catalog.json` and `manifest.json` is not in there as they are supposed to in the new v3 format.

What am i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my problem was, that inside the vbproj file (or csproj for most others) there was an import at the top like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="..\..\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.1.192\build\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.15.1.192\build\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.props')" />
    <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.14.3.25407\build\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.14.3.25407\build\Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools.props')" />
    ....
```

As you can see this project file has imports for both the new version and the old one of the BuildTools. I'm not sure why this happens, as all i did was update the VSSDK BuildTools via NuGet. I also tried to completely uninstall the BuildTools ticking `Force uninstall` but it seems to have remained through everything I tried.

So if you experience similar problems, look at your vbproj/csproj file if it has imports for older versions of the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools

Comment: I have the same problem migrating a VSIX project to 2017 with exactly the same result. Unfortunately, the solution above does not apply to my project. Can you please help with more suggestions. You can find my project at https://github.com/vmelamed/vm/tree/master/Aspects/Visix/AddRelatedClasses. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One problem that I see is that the manifest.json and catalog.json are not created...

Answer (score 1):

You must also upgrade the BuildTools package, the error you get indicate that this did not happen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-migrate-extensibility-projects-to-visual-studio-2017

Comment: If you mean the Microsoft.VSSDK.BuildTools then this is already upgraded to version 15.1.192. Forgot the BuildTools part in the original question. Going to edit this in.

Comment: Maybe VsixType? https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/blob/master/src/GUI/SqlCe35Toolbox/VSToolbox.csproj#L18

Comment: Tried adding that to the project file. No luck.

Comment: Can you share your csproj file?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just noticed the problem thanks to you. Looking in my vbproj file (its a Visual Basic .NET project) i noticed at the top that it had an import BOTH for the new version of Microsot VSSDK BuildTools (14.x and 15.x). No idea why but removing the import for the old version did the trick!

Comment: That is why I wanted to see your csproj/vbproj file!